# Prevent animation bobbing with middle aligned divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created this simple animation to represent some fake audio. I set the bars to be middle aligned within their container, but they are bobbing up and down depending on the height of the other bars. I figured by placing them in a container with a fixed height they would always stay in the middle.

**HTML**

```
<div class="bars">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bars {
    height:40px;
}
.bar {
    width:2px;
    background-color:green;
    transition: all 500ms;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:-2px;
}
```

**JS**

```
function Bars() {
    this.interval = null;
    this.refresh = 500;
}

Bars.prototype = {
    start: function () {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.animate.bind(this), this.refresh);
},
stop: function () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
},
animate: function () {
        $('.bar').each(function () {
            var h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);
            $(this).css('height', h + "px");
        });
    }
}

var bars = new Bars();
bars.start();
```

Please see my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/73u2n82d/3/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a 'hidden' bar with a stable height to smooth things out - I also increased the height of the bars for that final feeling of smoothness. Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/efr4my6y/

So I added a div.hidden with the following css:

```
.hidden {
  background-color: transparent;
  width:2px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:-2px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `vertical-align: top` and then calculate the `margin-top` in the animate function

```js
function Bars() {
    this.interval = null;
    this.refresh = 500;
}

Bars.prototype = {
    start: function () {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.animate.bind(this), this.refresh);
    },
    stop: function () {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },
    animate: function () {
        $('.bar').each(function () {
            var h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            var margintop = (100-h)/2.0;
            console.log(h, margintop);
            $(this).css('height', h + "px");
            $(this).css('margin-top', margintop + "px");
        });
    }
}

var bars = new Bars();
bars.start();
```

```css
.bars {
    height:100px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.bar {
    width:5px;
    background-color:gray;
    transition: all 500ms;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin:-2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bars">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```